# AJAX request doesn't display any data I have requested?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to display data from a JSON link. I've tried numerous ways of displaying it, but it either doesn't appear, displays `undefined` or `[object, Object]`.

I expect the outcome to be `France, 4, 1` etc. shown in table form.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://worldcup.sfg.io/teams/group_results?group_id=A", function(data) {
    var group_data = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
      group_data += '<tr>';
      group_data += '<td>' + data.ordered_teams[i].country + '</td>';
      group_data += '<td>' + data.ordered_teams[i].wins + '</td>';
      group_data += '<td>' + data.ordered_teams[i].losses + '</td>';
      group_data += '</tr>';
    });
    $('#group_A_table').append(group_data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <h1>Group Stages</h1>
  <h2>Group A</h2>
  <br />
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="group_A_table">
    <tr>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Wins</th>
      <th>Losses</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

This is what the JSON link looks like - https://worldcup.sfg.io/teams/group_results

```js
[{
  "id": 1,
  "letter": "A",
  "ordered_teams": [{
    "id": 1,
    "country": "France",
    "alternate_name": null,
    "fifa_code": "FRA",
    "group_id": 1,
    "group_letter": "A",
    "wins": 4,
    "draws": 0,
    "losses": 1,
    "games_played": 5,
    "points": 12,
    "goals_for": 10,
    "goals_against": 4,
    "goal_differential": 6
  },{
    "id": 3,
    "country": "Norway",
    "alternate_name": null,
    "fifa_code": "NOR",
    "group_id": 1,
    "group_letter": "A",
    "wins": 2,
    "draws": 1,
    "losses": 2,
    "games_played": 5,
    "points": 7,
    "goals_for": 7,
    "goals_against": 7,
    "goal_differential": 0
  },
```

Comment: Where is `i` initialised? You seem to be missing a loop over `ordered_teams`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two issues here. Firstly you've defined `i`, yet you're using a `$.each()` loop which receives the `key` and `value` of the items in the loop, not the index, hence you're getting an `i is undefined` error.

Once that's fixed the second problem is that `data` is an array and `ordered_teams` is property within the 0th element of that array. As such you need to loop over `data[0].ordered_teams` instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://worldcup.sfg.io/teams/group_results?group_id=A", function(data) {
    var group_data = '';
    $.each(data[0].ordered_teams, function(key, team) {
      group_data += '<tr>';
      group_data += '<td>' + team.country + '</td>';
      group_data += '<td>' + team.wins + '</td>';
      group_data += '<td>' + team.losses + '</td>';
      group_data += '</tr>';
    });
    $('#group_A_table').append(group_data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <h1>Group Stages</h1>
  <h2>Group A</h2>
  <br />
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="group_A_table">
    <tr>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Wins</th>
      <th>Losses</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Finally note that you can make the logic a little more succinct by using `map()` and string interpolation, try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://worldcup.sfg.io/teams/group_results?group_id=A", function(data) {
    var group_data = data[0].ordered_teams.map(function(obj) {
      return `<tr><td>${obj.country}</td><td>${obj.wins}</td><td>${obj.losses}</td></tr>`;
    }).join('');
    $('#group_A_table').append(group_data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <h1>Group Stages</h1>
  <h2>Group A</h2>
  <br />
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="group_A_table">
    <tr>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Wins</th>
      <th>Losses</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several issues:

- The `ordered_teams` array you are trying to iterate is contained inside the first object of the `data` array, while you're trying to iterate the `data` array itself.
- You are using `key` and `value` in the [`jQuery.each`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function and an undefined `i` index inside of it.

The following code should work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://worldcup.sfg.io/teams/group_results?group_id=A", function(data) {
    if (data && data.length > 0) {
      var group_data = '';
      $(data[0].ordered_teams).each(function(i, ordered_team) {
        group_data += '<tr>';
        group_data += '<td>' + ordered_team.country + '</td>';
        group_data += '<td>' + ordered_team.wins + '</td>';
        group_data += '<td>' + ordered_team.losses + '</td>';
        group_data += '</tr>';
      });
      $('#group_A_table').append(group_data);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <h1>Group Stages</h1>
  <h2>Group A</h2>
  <br />
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="group_A_table">
    <tr>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Wins</th>
      <th>Losses</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

*N.B.* Before accessing `data[0]` I'd also suggest you to check that `data` contains at least one item.

Answer (score 0):

As per this API https://worldcup.sfg.io/teams/group_results
the result have 2 iterations.
1 for group and 2 for teams.
so if you want to get only for First group team which is Team A 
then you have to pass 0 in data like this data[0].ordered_teams
and then iterate for ordered_teams then you get your answer.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("https://worldcup.sfg.io/teams/group_results", function (data) {
            var group_data = '';
            console.log(data)
            $.each(data[0].ordered_teams, function (key, value) {
                group_data += '<tr>';
                group_data += '<td>' + data[0].ordered_teams[key].country + '</td>';
                group_data += '<td>' + data[0].ordered_teams[key].wins + '</td>';
                group_data += '<td>' + data[0].ordered_teams[key].losses + '</td>';
                group_data += '</tr>';
            });
            $('#group_A_table').append(group_data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

if you want all group team in list then do this.

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("https://worldcup.sfg.io/teams/group_results", function(data){ 
            var group_data = '';
            console.log(data)
            $.each(data, function(key, value){
                $.each(data[key].ordered_teams, function(keya, value){
                    console.log(data[key].ordered_teams[keya].country)
                console.log(data[key].ordered_teams[keya].wins)
                console.log(data[key].ordered_teams[keya].losses)
                group_data += '<tr>';
                group_data += '<td>'+data[key].ordered_teams[keya].country+'</td>';
                group_data += '<td>'+data[key].ordered_teams[keya].wins+'</td>';
                group_data += '<td>'+data[key].ordered_teams[keya].losses+'</td>';
                group_data += '</tr>';
            });
            });
            $('#group_A_table').append(group_data);    
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need any counter variable like 'i' while using $.each loop,

Index and value counters are already defined in your case,

Your code should work with following modifications::

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://worldcup.sfg.io/teams/group_results?group_id=A", function(data) {
    var group_data = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
      group_data += '<tr>';
      group_data += '<td>' + value.country + '</td>';
      group_data += '<td>' + value.wins + '</td>';
      group_data += '<td>' + value.losses + '</td>';
      group_data += '</tr>';
    });
    $('#group_A_table').append(group_data);
  });
});
```